# Convert Local time to UTC before 1970

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, epoch, pytz

I'm trying to get UTC times for dates before 1970 but `tz` and `tzinfo` in Python only contain timezone databases for dates post-1970.

If I'm trying to find the UTC time for a date before 1970, say, Bill Clinton's birthday:

August 16, 1946 8:51AM
Hope, AK

`datetime` and `tzinfo` will return `16 Aug 1946 13:51 UTC`

But it turns out that that is incorrect because it uses Chicago's timezone (which had its own timezone)

How can I find the proper time conversion and trust it for dates before 1970 in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time zone rules as we know them today came into play around 1900, see e.g. [P. Eggert's tz repo](https://github.com/eggert/tz). So Bill Clinton's birthday should not suffer from missing tz rules.

Ex, using pytz (deprecated):

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

bday = "August 16, 1946 8:51AM Hope, AK"
# Hope, AK is not a time zone, so strip it
bday = bday.rstrip(" Hope, AK")

# Hope in Arkansas uses US Central time, so we can use
tz = pytz.timezone("America/Chicago")

bday_dt = tz.localize(datetime.strptime(bday, "%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p"))

print(bday_dt)
# 1946-08-16 08:51:00-05:00
print(bday_dt.astimezone(pytz.UTC))
# 1946-08-16 13:51:00+00:00
```

...or using Python 3.9's [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html)

```py
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

bday_dt = datetime.strptime(bday, "%B %d, %Y %I:%M%p").replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo("America/Chicago"))

print(bday_dt)
# 1946-08-16 08:51:00-05:00
print(bday_dt.astimezone(ZoneInfo("UTC")))
# 1946-08-16 13:51:00+00:00
```

Comment: I edited my question I meant it returns 13:51 but should return 14:51. Reason is, whenever I use Google TimeZone's API that supposedly keeps track of historical time zones, I get the following response: `{
   "dstOffset" : 3600,
   "rawOffset" : -21600,
   "status" : "OK",
   "timeZoneId" : "America/Chicago",
   "timeZoneName" : "GMT-05:00"
}`  Which corresponds to 14:51 UTC. I have no clue which one to trust

Comment: Actually I realized I gave the API the wrong timestamp (it used EDT instead of CST) thanks!

Comment: Actually yeah it should be rawOffset + DTS  @FObersteiner  thus it returns 14:51 instead of the 13:51. Any idea on if I should trust this API over zoneinfo?

Comment: @MichealS.Bingham raw + DST offset would be 18000s / 5 hours, 8:51 plus 5 hours is 13:51 (UTC). Without DST, it would be six hours UTC offset. So if I understand correctly, Google API and zoneinfo agree.